# Empty default tab in Bootstrap tabs container with iframes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get the iframe in the first tab to show on load, although it does show when I click it afterwards.  I've tried making tabs 2 or 3 the active tab, but it seems that the active tab, which ever tab it is, never shows its contents on load.  Thanks.  fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nmt2pmtx/

```
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css


div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
     <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#dpa" data-toggle="tab">DPA</a></li>
     <li><a href="#rn" data-toggle="tab">Antwon</a></li>
   </ul>

   <div class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" data-src="http://bing.com">
       <iframe src="" width="300" height="203" frameborder="0"></iframe>
   </div>

   <div class="tab-pane" id="dpa" data-src="http://www.drugpolicy.org/">
     <iframe src=""></iframe>
   </div>

   <div class="tab-pane" id="rn" data-src="http://bing.com">
      <iframe src="" width="500" height="203" frameborder="0"></iframe>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>




$('#myTabs').bind('show', function(e) {
paneID = $(e.target).attr('href');
src = $(paneID).attr('data-src');

// if the iframe hasn't already been loaded once
if ($(paneID + " iframe").attr("src") == "") {
$(paneID + " iframe").attr("src", src);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

remove active class from Home tab. 
on load it does not shows any frame. On click only it shows.

http://jsfiddle.net/nmt2pmtx/2/`<li class=""><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>`

Comment: Thanks @Ram_UI.  That was the answer I feared.  Isn't there a way to show an iframe as a default on load?